# Perl regular expression to match input for port numbers

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to write a **regular expression** that would only accept valid input that would qualify as a port number. I want to only accept input for the characters 0-9 and no special characters. The number should not be longer than 5 characters.

I read user input using this method.

```
my $port_number = <>;
```

I know that the regular expression should look something like this.

```
^[0-9]*$
```

How do I combine the regular expression with the reading of the command line input without using an **if** statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$result = ($port_number =~ m/^[0-9]{1,5}$/);
```

`$result` will be set to 1 if the `$port_number` matches your criteria, and will be set to 0 otherwise.